# Regex to Replace text without using lookbehind

Tags: regex, vba

I have a text file with several items (blocks of text) like the following:

```
SAMPLE
ITEM_ID sample_id_0000028
blah blah
ABCD <--- do NOT remove
blah blah blah
blah blah
blah
SAMPLE_END


SAMPLE
ITEM_ID sample_id_0000033
other text
more text
ABCD <--- Remove this
more text
SAMPLE_END

SAMPLE
ITEM_ID sample_id_00041
ABCD <--- do NOT remove
blah blah blah
blah
SAMPLE_END
```

I want to replace/remove the instance of `ABCD` that occurs in the item with ID `sample_id_0000033`. The challenge is that there are other instances of `ABCD` in the file that I want to leave alone.  Also, the number of lines between the `ITEM_ID` and `ABCD` varies from item to item, and it's possible that `ABCD` will not be found in the specified item.

I must manipulate the file via vbscript in VBA. I figured I would use Regex to do this, but VBA does not support regular expressions with lookbehind. Is there a pattern that can be used to accomplish this with negative lookahead or something simpler than that?

I would execute the regex on a string defined as `textfile.ReadAll`, where `textfile` is a TextStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
pattern: (ITEM_ID sample_id_0000033\D(?:[^S]|S(?!=AMPLE_END))+?)ABCD
replace: $1
```

or better, this:

```
pattern: (ITEM_ID sample_id_0000033\D(?:[^\r]+\r\n)+?)ABCD
replace: $1
```

or shorter as acheong87 example:

```
pattern: (sample_id_0000033\D(?:[^\r]+\r\n)+?)ABCD
replace: $1
```

Comment: The first one worked for me. Thank you! However, any pattern including `\n` is not matching as expected in VBA.

Comment: @Excellll: Yes, \n must be replaced by \r\n (CRLF is the natural new line in windows). I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

You need *some* way of delimiting each "block", for example, by the blank line between each block. For example, you might replace

```
(sample_id_0000033(?:\r|\n|\r\n)(?:.*\S.*(?:\r|\n|\r\n))*)ABCD
```

with

```
$1
```

Here's what's going on.

1. `sample_id_0000033` is self-explanatory.
2. I write `(?:\r|\n|\r\n)` as longhand for "any kind of linebreak", whether CR (Mac), LF (UNIX), or CR/LF (DOS). The shorthand is `(?:\r|\r?\n)`. The reason I'm not writing something like `[\r\n]+` or `\s+` is that we do *not* want to match more than a *single* linebreak.
3. Then, we want to skip over lines that contain at least one *non-whitespace* character, *i.e.* non-blank lines: `.*\S.*`. Plus the any-kind-of-linebreak, of course, immediately following. Note that the wildcard `.` does *not* match linebreaks by default—if you're in dot-matches-newlines mode, then you should use `[^\r\n]` instead of the `.`.
4. The non-capturing groups `(?: ... )` are optional, but good practice, since we don't plan on using those groups.
5. If we finally meet a line with `ABCD`, then everything before it is captured in `$1` and restored as-is via replacement—leaving out the `ABCD`. If we *don't* meet a line with `ABCD` before we meet a blank line, the match fails and nothing is replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following powershell example of a universal regex and logic. This does not use any regex lookarounds and will match ABCD on any of the `blah blah` lines.

You should be able to rewrite this concept into your VBA logic.

## Example

```
$Matches = @()
$String = 'SAMPLE
ITEM_ID sample_id_0000028
blah blah
ABCD <--- do NOT remove
blah blah blah
blah blah
blah
SAMPLE_END


SAMPLE
ITEM_ID sample_id_0000033
other text
more text
ABCD <--- Remove this
more text
SAMPLE_END

SAMPLE
ITEM_ID sample_id_00041
ABCD <--- do NOT remove
blah blah blah
blah
SAMPLE_END

SAMPLE
ITEM_ID sample_id_0000028
blah blah
ABCD <--- do NOT remove
blah blah blah
blah blah
blah
SAMPLE_END
SAMPLE
ITEM_ID sample_id_0000033
other text
more text
ABCD <--- Remove this
more text
SAMPLE_END
SAMPLE
ITEM_ID sample_id_00041
ABCD <--- do NOT remove
blah blah blah
blah
SAMPLE_END'


 $NewString = $String
([regex]'(sample_id_0000033((.|\n|\r)*?)SAMPLE_END)').matches($String) | foreach {
    write-host  --------------------------------------------
    Write-Host "found at $($_.Groups[1].Index) = '$($_.Groups[1].Value)'"
    Write-Host "found at $($_.Groups[2].Index) = '$($_.Groups[2].Value)'"

    $ThisRecord = $_.Groups[1].Value

    $InnerText = $_.Groups[2].Value
    $NewInnerText = $InnerText -replace "ABCD", "I like kittens"

    $NewRecord = $ThisRecord -replace $InnerText, $NewInnerText

    write-host
    Write-Host NewRecord:
    Write-Host $NewRecord

    $NewString = $NewString -replace $ThisRecord, $NewRecord


    } # next match
```

## Yields

Note in this example I left the `<--- Remove this` values on the string so that it would be easier to identify where the changes were made

```
--------------------------------------------
found at 136 = 'sample_id_0000033
other text
more text
ABCD <--- Remove this
more text
SAMPLE_END'
found at 153 = '
other text
more text
ABCD <--- Remove this
more text
'

NewRecord:
sample_id_0000033
other text
more text
I like kittens <--- Remove this
more text
SAMPLE_END
--------------------------------------------
found at 452 = 'sample_id_0000033
other text
more text
ABCD <--- Remove this
more text
SAMPLE_END'
found at 469 = '
other text
more text
ABCD <--- Remove this
more text
'

NewRecord:
sample_id_0000033
other text
more text
I like kittens <--- Remove this
more text
SAMPLE_END
--------------------------------------------
New String
SAMPLE
ITEM_ID sample_id_0000028
blah blah
ABCD <--- do NOT remove
blah blah blah
blah blah
blah
SAMPLE_END


SAMPLE
ITEM_ID sample_id_0000033
other text
more text
I like kittens <--- Remove this
more text
SAMPLE_END

SAMPLE
ITEM_ID sample_id_00041
ABCD <--- do NOT remove
blah blah blah
blah
SAMPLE_END

SAMPLE
ITEM_ID sample_id_0000028
blah blah
ABCD <--- do NOT remove
blah blah blah
blah blah
blah
SAMPLE_END
SAMPLE
ITEM_ID sample_id_0000033
other text
more text
I like kittens <--- Remove this
more text
SAMPLE_END
SAMPLE
ITEM_ID sample_id_00041
ABCD <--- do NOT remove
blah blah blah
blah
SAMPLE_END
```

## Summary

1. Using this regex `(sample_id_0000033((.|\n|\r)*?)SAMPLE_END)` look for all blocks of text starting with sample_id_0000033 and ending with the next SAMPLE_END. Of course if you use a different delimiter for record end you'd need to include that here as well.
2. Behind the scenes Powershell hides how it populates the `$Matches` array with all found sub strings. These are then passed into the `foreach` loop where the `$_` is equivalent to the $Matches (in this case).
3. Inside the  `foreach` block we process each found instance of your match:

   - replacing the known text `ABCD` with a desired string `I like kittens` and store the resulting change into `$NewInnerText`. I'm creating a new variable here because `$InnerText` will not include the open and close strings which depending on the actual value of your `ABCD` could accidently change text in the end tags.
   - the `$NewRecord` is created from the results of replacing `$InnerText` with `$NewInnerText` inside `$ThisRecord`
   - with `$NewString` we then issue the replace `$ThisRecord` with `$NewRecord`

Comment: TIP: `(.|\n|\r)` is not a good way to match *anything-including-newlines*.  For one thing, you would have to tailor it to each flavor: in PowerShell (.NET) it would be `(.|\n)`, because `\n` is the only character that `.` doesn't match; in VBA (VBScript) you would have to use `(.|[\r\n\u2028\u2029])`.  But it's more efficient and less error-prone to use `.` in `DOTALL/Singleline` mode in those flavors that support it, and `[\s\S]` in ECMAScript flavors (JavaScript, VBScript, etc.).